Spring Authorizationserver and scope for google drive
Is it possible to configure spring AuthorizationServer to use google as login provider (yes) AND use google APIs (in question)? I basically use the official samples
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples demo-authorizationserver with federated idp google. messages-resource and demo-client are used for testing.
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google-idp:
            provider: google
            client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID:google-client-id}
            client-secret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET:google-client-secret}
            scope: openid, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
            client-name: Sign in with Google
        provider:
          google:
            user-name-attribute: email

Authorization Server Config (basically just added scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly")):
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/logged-out")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                .build();

        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        registeredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);

        return registeredClientRepository;
    }
}

When I access the resource the login page for google opens and I need to grant access to google drive also which looks fine to me. From my understanding I should be able to call google APIs in my messages-resource (RS) with this authorization. How to use this authorization later on to actually access the google drive?
